# Simple Pseudocode Code Question

Tags: pseudocode

I'm a little new to pseudocode. I understand what the code is saying, but having a hard time putting the pieces together. How should I be thinking to understand what this code is doing:

Suppose that a1, a2, . . . , ak is an array of k numbers. What does the following
code fragment do? Briefly explain why. Assume that all the indented lines
belong inside the loop.

```
1 for p := 1 to ⌊k/2⌋
2     t := ap
3     ap := ak−p+1
4     ak−p+1 := t
```

Comment: That's why I really dislike imperative pseudocode. Is basically sais nothing. And of course, an off-by-one error is almost impossible to detect.

Compare ;)
`reverse [] = []; reverse (h:t) = (reverse t) ++ [h]`

Comment: I also really dislike non-ASCII code. If you don't know what those funny symbols around the `k/2` mean, there's no way to "just Google it". If it said `floor` instead, you can search on this site and easily find out what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ookay,

```
1 for p := 1 to ⌊k/2⌋
```

means, we're going up to the half of the array.

```
2 t := ap
3 ap := ak−p+1
4 ak−p+1 := t
```

This pattern can be recognized as a "swap with temporary `t`". And what is swapped?

Well, `ap` and `ak-p+1`, one being the *`p`-th element from the array start*, the other one the *`p`-th one from the end*.

**So, to sum up**:

You swap the `n`-th first with the `n`-th last array value up to the half of the array. And afterwards? *The array is reversed*.

Note that your pseudocode-format looks really weird - and, most importantly - ambiguous.

Is `ak-p+1` equivalent to `a[k-p+1]` or to `a[k]-p+1` or `a[k-p]+1`? If not, how did you express the other ones.

So at first, I'll convert this code to an actual source like Python's, which is much easier to read.

**Edit**.

I) Well, as you posted, the array ranges from `a1` to `ak`.

II) Think how you could swap the values of two variables (`a` and `b`):

```
1 temp := a
2 a    := b
3 b    := temp
```

Of course, since you overwrote `a` with `b` in line *2*, you had to store the old `a` value in a temporary, which is `temp`.

Comment: this is a very bad pseudo code notation. How can one know it ak-p+1 means a[k-p+1] or a[k] - p + 1.

Comment: I'm very new to programming so recognizing these patterns is not common sense to me, yet. What exactly does 'swap with temporary t' mean? Also, at what value does the array start and what value does the array stop?

Comment: Edited the question. Go step by step!

Answer (score 0):

The loop mirrors the array to its central element as it changes a[p] with a[k-p+1] where a[p] is always on the "left" side of the array and a[k-p+1] is always on the "right" side.
t is a temporary variable.

Comment: Hmm ok. So what does this really mean? When I ran some numbers in there, it seemed like it would take a[k]-1 and it would decrement it by one each time the loop ran.