# Simply Pseudocode Question

Tags: pseudocode

I'm new to psuedocode, and I'm having trouble putting all the pieces together:

Here is the definition of a function named foo whose inputs are two integers and an array of integers `a[1] ... a[n]`.

```
1 Foo(k,m, a[1],...,a[n]) 
2   if (k < 1 or m > n or k > m) return 0 
3   else return a[k] + Foo(k+1,m,a[1],...,a[n])
```

Suppose that the input integers are `k=2` and `m=5` and the input array contains `[5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 8, 2]`. What value does Foo return? Using summation notation, give a general formula for what Foo computes.

This one is making my head hurt. Here's what I did so far:

Line 2 has three conditional statements:

- If k<1 // if 2<1..this is false
- If m>n // if 5 is greater than the amount of values in the array, which is 7, so this is false
- If k>m // if 2>5, this is false

So this function will display line 3. Line 3 says:

- return `a[k]` which is `a[2]` which is the second value of the array, which is 6. So take 6 and add it to `(2+1, 5, a[1].....,a[n])`

Is what I have done correct up there? If so, how would I know what `a[n]` is? Am I supposed to be finding that? What would be the final result of all this?

Comment: you asked this same question a couple days ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595256/simple-pseudocode-code-question .  Did you not like the answers you got?

Comment: gah, accidental edit war, I tried to rollback to exclude my revision, the markdown and preview look right but this screen doesn't. I'm stopping before I break it more. Sorry.

Comment: atk- this is not the same question.

Comment: you'reright. sorry.  The duplicate title and similar issue threw me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So take 6 and add it to (2+1, 5,
>   a[1].....,a[n])

Take 6 and add it to **Foo**(2+1, 5, a[1].....,a[n]).  It's a recursive function.  You have to evaluate the function again with k=3 and m=5.

Comment: Recursive? So its not as simple as taking line 3 and displaying the result? So 

6+(2+1, 5, a[1].....,a[n])

would be 6+(3, 5, 5,6,2,3,4,8,2)

which is 6+(38) which is 44? Is this the correct answer?

Comment: Foo(2, 5, a) = 6 + Foo(3, 5, a).  Foo(3, 5, a) = 2 + Foo(4, 5, a).  Foo(4, 5, a) = 3 + Foo(5, 5, a).  Foo(5, 5, a) = 4 + Foo(6, 5, a).  Foo(6, 5, a) = 0.

Comment: What the?? What happened there? How did you do this?

Comment: **recursion** *n.* If you don't understand recursion, see **recursion**.

Comment: I know what recursion is its when a function calls itself. Ok I think I see what you did there, but what exactly is 'a'? Is that just the sum of all the values in the array?

Comment: a is the array itself.  I didn't feel like typing `a[1]...a[n]`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: that function returns the sum of all the numbers a[k], a[k+1], ... a[m].

What you're doing is correct so far. The "n" is just a placeholder meaning the last element of the array. So if your input array is `{5,6,2,3,4,8,2}`, `n = 7` (cause your have seven elements), and `a[n] = 2`.

But why it returns the sum of all numbers a[k], a[k+1], ... a[m], you should find out for yourself. Just continue with your analysis. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused because your pseudocode looks like real code to me. I may be wrong, but we are taught to write pseudocode differently, using plain English phrases.